# Carrierwave implementation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I've just finished creating a simple Carrierwave file upload system (via the example at http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)

Here is my model:

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :course, :qa_complete, :qa_id, :subject, :title, 
  :translate_complete, :translator_id, :type_complete, :typer_id, :video_id, :due_date, :translation_handwritten

  validates :video_id, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true #add uniqueness in db too
  mount_uploader :translation_handwritten, TranslationsUploader
end
```

Here is my form view:

```
<%= form_for @video.video_id, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.file_field :translation_handwritten %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit :Upload %></p>
<% end %>
```

Here is my uploader:

```
class TranslationsUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def default_url
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg pdf png)
  end
end
```

Whenever I try actually uploading, however, it redirects and gives a flash notice appropriately but does not actually upload to image. When I print @video.translation_handwritten.url it shows /assets/fallback/default.png which is my default url. Where might the issue be? I've been staring at this forever...

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

This might not be your only problem, but you need to change

```
form_for @video.video_id, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
```

to

```
form_for @video, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
```

If that doesn't fix it, you should post your controller's `create` method.